# Enforcing row-level security in a shared postgres pool

Tags: postgresql, sql-injection, node-postgres, row-level-security

I'm working on a typical client-server webapp. It is using a system somewhat like GraphQL where the client has some flexibility in specifying what data it needs, without custom API endpoints for every type of data. The server is running node, and is using node-postgres with a typical [`pg.Pool`](https://node-postgres.com/apis/pool). A client could send something like this:

```json
{select: '*', from: 'expenses', where: {'op': 'gt', 'lhs': 'expenses.amount', 'rhs': 20}}
```

which would be translated to `SELECT * FROM expenses WHERE expenses.amount > $1` (given `$1` = 20). With enough care, this system can be made safe from injection attacks.

I'd also like to incorporate row-level security policies. For example:

```sql
create policy only_see_own_expenses on expenses using (expenses.user_id = <USER ID>);
```

**As an extra security barrier, I want to make sure that even if an injection attack is succesful, a client can not "unset" its user ID.**

I've seen `<USER ID>` been defined in a few ways:

1. `current_user`, in which case every user of the app also needs a postgres user/role
2. An arbitrary setting like `current_setting('myapp.user_id')` in combination with a `SET LOCAL myapp.user_id = ...` at the start of a transaction

Approach (2) seems most flexible to me. I'd just wrap every generated SQL query in a `BEGIN; SET LOCAL myapp.user_id = 123; {generated query}; END;`. The problem is that an attacker could inject another `SET LOCAL` statement, and impersonate another user.

In approach (1) you can similarly wrap every generated query with a `SET ROLE ...` statement at the start, yielding the same problem. An alternative is to create a new connection for each query with that specific role. I believe postgres would never allow that connection to switch to another role. But setting up a new connection per query would result in a lot of overhead.

**How do I enforce row-level security without the performance hit of a new connection per query?**

Comment: "*I believe postgres would never allow that connection to switch to another role.*" - it does, actually. You need to distinguish the authentication role (that the connection was opened with), the [session user identifier](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-session-authorization.html) (which a superuser can impersonate), and the [current user identifier](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-role.html) that can be set to any role granted to the session user. So unless you create a separate login role for each user, an SQL injection could switch to an arbitrary role.

Answer (score 2):

As you observe, setting a placeholder parameter and using `SET LOCAL ROLE` to temporarily assume a different role can be subverted by attackers who can execute arbitrary SQL, like in an SQL injection attack.

I don't think that there is a way to accomplish what you want that is safe from SQL injection. The problem is a fundamental one: you handle authentication in the application, not in the database (where you are using a single application user to benefit from connection pooling), but you want to have the database handle authorization via row-level security. That requires a way for the application to tell the database what the application user is. Now the only way that the application can tell the database anything is by using SQL, and an attacker who can run arbitrary SQL statements can always subvert that.

I think that the only option for you is to harden your application against SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

> As an extra security barrier, I want to make sure that even if an injection attack is succesful, a client can not "unset" its user ID.

Your second solution is not only perfectly viable, it's exactly what many websites do. Sure, anyone can edit the `user_id` parameter in a cookie, URL, SQL statement or even custom protocol frame, but as long as you do not

1. expose the list of valid identifiers
2. make the identifiers easy/possible to guess/brute-force through
3. share or re-use them

changing it just makes no sense because you have nothing to change it *to*. If someone just "unsets" the id, it'll break their access. Same if they set it wrong. Your only concern is to make sure if they set it right, there's no way they got the other id from you. Assuming the above, having another token to change to means it was acquired outside the system, beyond your control (given, stolen, leaked - not by you), or that it's just multiple sessions of the same person and they have that access anyways.

That being said, by no means does it free you from the necessity to *also* lock down your SQL against injections and it kind of requires you to set up and manage this token-based authentication on top of everything else, which might be a challenge on its own. Make sure you know how [rules and privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-privileges.html) work and that you're not leaking anything through `security definer` routines or views with `security_barrier` off.

Comment: …or `security definer` views (ie. with `security_invoker` off, which is the default!)

Comment: Do I misunderstand, or are you advocating "security by obscurity"?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I'm not but I'm interested in how you got that impression

Comment: "As long as you do not make the identifiers easy/possible to guess/brute-force changing it just makes no sense because you have nothing to change it to." To find out if a certain UUID exists in a table that you cannot read owing to RLS, can't you just `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` a query and see if there was a row removed by a filter?

Comment: By all means, you can. But why? If you have a valid token, you don't need `explain analyze` to tell you that - if you're trying to test tokens in a brute-force attempt, that's just a slower way to do so. You could even load heavy batches of uuid guesses [all day up to the 1gig](https://doxygen.postgresql.org/memutils_8h.html) but it's worth reminding how sparse even regular uuids are and that in such scenario it is no longer a break-out attempt, it's a denial of service. It's not very different from any other password guessing game.

Comment: Still, guessing a key is one thing, guessing what it protects is another - it might even be easier to guess everything else but the keys. Doc I linked puts it well: *A malicious attacker might be able to infer something about the amount of unseen data, or even gain some information about the data distribution or most common values (since these things may affect the run time of the plan; or even, since they are also reflected in the optimizer statistics, the choice of plan). If these types of "covert channel" attacks are of concern, it is probably unwise to grant any access to the data at all.*

Comment: I like this idea, but it still requires some sort of special limit to the "authentication role" (see @Bergi's comment on the question). If my entire pool uses a rather privileged authentication role and then uses `SET ROLE less_privileged_role` to narrow it down (in combination with RLS) the only SQL injection necessary would be a `RESET ROLE`. But it's not impossible as in this system you wouldn't have that many roles :)

Comment: Maybe the bigger stumbling block is that this identifier needs to be unguessable *and* unretrievable given full access to the database. All objects that would normally refer to a simple (and guessable) user ID now need to refer to a user using this secret way of denoting a user. I can see that becoming a real headache when writing RLS policies.

Comment: This would only work if the common user role is restricted from the start, unable switch back. Leaving them the option to switch is like restricting a user while still leaving them the option to elevate to `root` via `sudo` - they can side-step all limitations at any time. `Unretrievable despite full access` is kind of self-contradictory.